# How do I change the color of all hyperlinks in a div (via inline styling)?

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="blah blah> <a href=”http://www.google.com”> is a red hyperlink,
but this text is all black</div>
```

I do not want to edit each hyperlink inside individually.

Answer (score 1):

Give your `<div>` it's own unique `id=""` attribute or if you have multiple divs, give them all the same `class=""` values.

Then use this rule:

```
<div class="className"><a href="http://foo">link</a></div>

.className a:link { color: red; }
```

or

```
<div id="identifier"><a href="http://foo">link</a></div>

#identifier a:link { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<style>
a {color: red;}
</style>
```

at the top of the HTML.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can add a jquery on document ready and target each hyperlink if you want it in-line. But best approach is still using the css approach shown by others above.

Here's via jquery:
$('div a').css('color', 'red');